# Problem with the save function of the metabox with radio buttons

Tags: php, wordpress, radio-button, custom-post-type

I have created the following metabox that allows me to upload files or share file links from the custom_post_type "library". The problem is that when trying to retrieve the data from the different fields from single-library.php, apparently some data is not being saved in the DB and therefore the query is not being performed.

The metabox is as follows:

```
    / Register the metabox
    function add_upload_file_metaboxes() {
        add_meta_box(
            'upload_file_metabox',
            'File Share',
            'swp_file_upload',
            'library',
            'normal',
            'high'
        );
    }
    add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_upload_file_metaboxes');
    
    // Render the metabox
function swp_file_upload($post) {
    // Retrieve the current values of the fields, if any
    $nonce = wp_create_nonce(plugin_basename(__FILE__));
    printf('<input type="hidden" name="podcastmeta_noncename" id="podcastmeta_noncename" value="%s" />', $nonce);

    $meta_fields = array(
        'download_file',
        'fileType',
        'mp4_video',
        'doc_file',
        'xls_file',
        'ppt_file',
        'pdf_file',
        'rar_file',
        'zip_file',
        'videoServer',
        'mp4_local_video',
        'youtube_video',
        'vimeo_video',
        'fileServer',
        'local_server',
        'drive_server',
        'external_server',
        'googledriveUrl',
        'drive_file',
        'drive_folder'
    );

    $values = array();
    foreach ($meta_fields as $field) {
        $values[$field] = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field, true);
    }

    ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>File Upload</legend>
        <label for="download_file">Upload or Paste the URL of your File</label><br />
        <input type="text" id="download_file" name="download_file" value="<?php echo $values['download_file']; ?>">
        <input type="button" id="upload_file_button" class="button" value="Upload File">
        <input type="button" id="reset_button" value="Reset">
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="url_error_fieldset" style="display: none;">
      <legend>Error:</legend>
      <p id="url_error_message"></p>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="file_type_group">
        <legend>File Type</legend>
        <?php foreach (array('mp4_video', 'doc_file', 'xls_file', 'ppt_file', 'pdf_file', 'rar_file', 'zip_file') as $field) : ?>
            <input type="radio" id="<?php echo $field; ?>" name="file_type" value="<?php echo $field; ?>" <?php checked($values['fileType'], $field); ?>>
            <label for="<?php echo $field; ?>" class="<?php echo $field; ?>"><?php echo strtoupper(str_replace('_', ' ', $field)); ?></label>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </fieldset>

    <div id="video_server_group">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Video Server</legend>
            <?php foreach (array('mp4_local_video', 'youtube_video', 'vimeo_video') as $field) : ?>
                <input type="radio" id="<?php echo $field; ?>" name="video_server" value="<?php echo $field; ?>" <?php checked($values['videoServer'], $field); ?>>
                <label for="<?php echo $field; ?>" class="<?php echo $field; ?>"><?php echo ucfirst(str_replace('_', ' ', $field)); ?></label>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div id="file_server_group">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>File Server</legend>
            <?php foreach (array('local_server', 'drive_server', 'external_server') as $field) : ?>
                <input type="radio" id="<?php echo $field; ?>" name="file_server" value="<?php echo $field; ?>" <?php checked($values['fileServer'], $field); ?>>
                <label for="<?php echo $field; ?>" class="<?php echo $field; ?>"><?php echo ucfirst(str_replace('_', ' ', $field)); ?></label>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div id="google_drive_url_type_group">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Google URL Type</legend>
            <?php foreach (array('drive_file', 'drive_folder') as $field) : ?>
                <input type="radio" id="<?php echo $field; ?>" name="google_drive_url_type" value="<?php echo $field; ?>" <?php checked($values['googledriveUrl'], $field); ?>>
                <label for="<?php echo $field; ?>" class="<?php echo $field; ?>"><?php echo ucfirst(str_replace('_', ' ', $field)); ?></label>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="file_txt_id" id="file_txt_id" value="" />
    <?php
} 

/** Save the metabox values **/
function save_podcasts_meta($post_id) {
    // Verify the nonce before proceeding
    if (!isset($_POST['podcastmeta_noncename']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['podcastmeta_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__))) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // Check if this is an autosave
    if (wp_is_post_autosave($post_id)) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // Check if this is a revision
    if (wp_is_post_revision($post_id)) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // Check the user's permissions
    if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // Define an array of fields to update and sanitize
    $fields_to_update = array(
        'download_file',
        'fileType',
        'mp4_video',
        'doc_file',
        'xls_file',
        'ppt_file',
        'pdf_file',
        'rar_file',
        'zip_file',
        'videoServer',
        'mp4_local_video',
        'youtube_video',
        'vimeo_video',
        'fileServer',
        'local_server',
        'drive_server',
        'external_server',
        'googledriveUrl',
        'drive_file',
        'drive_folder',
    );

    // Loop through the fields to update and sanitize them
    foreach ($fields_to_update as $field) {
        if (isset($_POST[$field])) {
            $sanitized_field = sanitize_text_field($_POST[$field]);
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field, $sanitized_field);
        }
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_podcasts_meta', 10, 1);
```

Firstly, I want to try to correct the metabox so that I can obtain the data from each of the radio buttons, for example, to check if the doc_file or pdf_file radio button from the file_type group is selected or if the drive_file or drive_folder button is selected in order to perform a logical condition.
The data from the download_file field is being obtained correctly, but apparently there are issues with the information from the radio buttons.

For example, I have created a logical condition that checks if the drive_file radio button is selected. If so, it checks the download_file field to see if it is a Google Drive URL. If it is, a function should be passed to the URL to retrieve the ID of the URL and store it in the $driveFile variable.

The template for show download button your name is file-down.php and is called from single-library.php:

```
<?php
global $file_down;
$file_down = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'download_file', true);
// Obtener ID de URl de Google Drive
function get_drive_id($url){
    preg_match('/\/file\/d\/(.+?)\//', $url, $result);
    return $result[1];
}
global $driveFile;
$driveFile = get_drive_id($file_down);

// Obtiene los valores de los campos personalizados 
global $file_type;
global $file_server;
global $video_server;
global $googleDriveUrl;
$file_type = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'fileType', true);
$video_server = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'videoServer', true);
$file_server = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'fileServer', true);
$googleDriveUrl = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '$googledriveUrl', true);

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    if ( get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'drive_file', true) ) {
        if ( strpos($file_down, 'drive.google.com') !== false ) {
            ?>
            <div class="doc-download">
                <a class="link-download" href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=<?php echo $driveFile; ?>" target="_blank" title="<?php echo __('Download','domainname'); ?> <?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                    <?php echo __('Download', 'domainname'); ?> ID: <?php echo $fileDrive; ?>
                </a>
            </div>
            <?php
        } else {
            ?>
            <div class="doc-download">
                <a class="link-download" href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=<?php echo $file_down; ?>" target="_blank" title="<?php echo __('Download','domainname'); ?> <?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                    <?php echo __('Download', 'domainname'); ?>
                </a>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
    }elseif ( get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'doc_file', true) || get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'xls_file', true) || get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'ppt_file', true) || get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'pdf_file', true) || get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'rar_file', true) || get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'zip_file', true) ) { ?>
        <div class="doc-download">
            <a class="link-download" href="<?php echo $file_down; ?>" target="_blank" title="<?php echo __('Download','domainname'); ?> <?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                <?php echo __('Download', 'domainname'); ?>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php
    } elseif(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'youtube_video', true) == true) { ?>
            <div class="youtube-download">
                <?php include_once(TEMPLATEPATH . '/youtube_dl.php'); ?>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
    <?php }else { ?>
        <div class="doc-download">
            <a class="link-download" data-nameplugin="File-<?php the_ID(); ?>" href="<?php echo $driveFile; ?>" title="<?php echo __('Download','domainname'); ?> <?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark" download>
                <?php echo __('Download', 'domainname'); ?>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } else { ?>               
    <?php if (empty($file_down)) { ?>  .      
    <?php } else { ?>
       <div class="doc-download">
            <a class="showbox" href="#login" title="<?php echo __('Login','cyberdocentes'); ?>">
                <?php echo __('Download', 'domainname'); ?>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
<?php }?>
```

The problem is that the logical conditions do not evaluate when the radio button is selected, instead the "else" result is returned for all logical conditions:

```
<?php } else { ?>
            <div class="doc-download">
                <a class="link-download" data-nameplugin="File-<?php the_ID(); ?>" href="<?php echo $driveFile; ?>" title="<?php echo __('Download','domainname'); ?> <?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark" download>
                    <?php echo __('Download', 'domainname'); ?>
                </a>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: _"if I execute that function in a PHP file outside the WordPress installation, it works correctly"_ - not sure what you mean by that; your code contains multiple calls to functions provided _by_ WordPress, so it is unclear how that would even work.

Comment: If I put the function to extract the google drive url id in the theme's functions.php, when I run the function from the single-library.php, it's as if the function doesn't exist. Outside of the WP install if it works even if I put the function inside the single-php

Comment: Well then you will have to do a bit of debugging, and start by figuring out _which_ of those conditions makes it fail.

Comment: Btw., why are you using `global` so much? So far it looks like that was completely superfluous here.